# Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'env' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the children which comes under "variable" drive or "env" drive and I have location set to "Alias" drive. As mentioned in the tutorial of HeyIamScriptingGuy : http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23978_Dnl_L.wmv . Seek video to 18:35 and you'll see he could do so, But for me it always show the following error:

```
PS Alias:\> Get-ChildItem env
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'env' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

So finally I check if those drives really exists or not and which is impossible that it won't exist.

```
PS Alias:\> Get-PSProvider

Name                 Capabilities                                      Drives
----                 ------------                                      ------
Registry             ShouldProcess, Transactions                       {HKLM, HKCU}
Alias                ShouldProcess                                     {Alias}
Environment          ShouldProcess                                     {Env}
FileSystem           Filter, ShouldProcess, Credentials                {C, D, E}
Function             ShouldProcess                                     {Function}
Variable             ShouldProcess                                     {Variable}
WSMan                Credentials                                       {WSMan}
Certificate          ShouldProcess                                     {Cert}
```

So as you can see, I do have those drives available. Even though I am not able to get ChildItem of any drive when I have location set to Alias Drive.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: _Am I missing anything ?_ A colon. `Get-ChildItem env:`. `Get-ChildItem c` would also fail. You would instinctively add C: for that one though. Currently you are telling it to find an item in the working directory of the provider. I would answer but I suspect this will be removed.

Comment: Reread the comment. I added why it doesnt work. PowerShell assumes you are referring to an object in the working directory of the current provider. How else would it tell the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing anything ?

Yes. A colon.

Without it PowerShell assumes you are referring to an object in the working directory of the current provider. Assuming the file system provider: If you were to create a folder called "env" and pop a text file in it that file would be returned by your code above.

This is supported by [documentation from TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847791.aspx)

> To view the contents of a provider drive, use the Get-Item or Get-ChildItem
>       cmdlets. Type the drive name **followed by a colon (:)**. For example, to 
>       view the contents of the Alias: drive, type:

In your specific case you are in the alias provider and "env" is not an alias (at least not be default). `Get-ChildItem ls` would have returned something though.

---

Therefore adding a colon to any of the drives should allow you to reference it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Kept seeing

> gc : Cannot find path 'Env:\XXCOMPUTERNAMEXX' because it does not
>   exist.

and regardless of what name I put there it errored everytime.

I removed it and the script runs fine w/o it.

Windows Server 2012r2